# C++ question: I'm having problems writing array of doubles (single precision 32 bit) to a disc file as 4-byte IEEE754 format

Tags: c++, arrays, file, format

I have an application I'm trying to write in which will take a table of numbers (generated by user) and write the table to a file on disc. This file will then later be transferred to an Arduino AVR device over USB to its EEPROM.
The format I wish to save this information in on disc is 4-byte Little Endian as just raw Hex data. My table array called "tbl1Array[]" in my code below has been cast as a double.
Below is a snippet of the bunk code I have in place now, in-line following some array preparation code. The file open/close works fine, and in fact, data DOES get transferred to the file, but the format is not what I want.

```
        ofstream fileToOutput("318file.bin");                  
            for (int i=0; i<41; i++)    
            {
                fileToOutput << tbl1Array[i];            
            }
            fileToOutput.close();
```

THE PROBLEM is that what is written to the file is a hex ASCII representation of the decimal value. Not what I want! I don't know what I need to do to get my array as a nice neat concatenated list of 4-byte Little Endian words for my doubles that I can later read from within the Arduino code. I have a working method for transferring the file to the Arduino using AVRDUDE (tested and confirmed), so my only real hang-up is getting these doubles in my applications' array to 4-byte IEEE754 on disc. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Regards - Mark

Comment: See [write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

Comment: A `double` is typically represented using 8 bytes, not 4. You would typically need to convert the array of `double` to an array of `float` (e.g. copy elements of one by value to the other) - not just casting. Also, to perform binary I/O, the file/stream must be opened in binary mode - by default `ofstream` and `istream` are both opened in text mode. Also use binary I/O.   Lastly, depending on what platform you are running on, `float` and `double` are not guaranteed to have a IEEE754 representation - on those platforms you would need to explicitly translate `float` to an IEEE754 representation.

Comment: The AVR c/c++ supports float only. If you use double, it'll be float again.

Comment: I was able to re-cast my array as a float (on declaration), so I think that addressed that issue. Also, not sure if this was the thing to do to make the file/stream open in binary mode, but I tried the following.ofstream fileToOutput("319file.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);                  
    for (int i=0; i<41; i++) 
    {
     fileToOutput << tbl1Array[i];                   
    }
    fileToOutput.close();

Comment: (cont) so, I am still seeing the same results as I had originally. Looks like text in my output file. My confusion with double/float was from working mostly with the AVR devices and they see them as the same (I think). Anyway, I'm using floats as my array and I included the ios::binary in the fie open. No change. Any other ideas?

Comment: `fileToOutput << tbl1Array[i]` does not do binary I/O.   It does formatted output, which is generally geared for text (non-binary) streams.     `ostream`s have a `write()` member function that does binary output, and `istream`s have a `read()` member function that does binary input.   The results of mixing (e.g. opening a file for binary I/O and writing with formatted operations) won't typically be what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In a text stream, the new-line character is **translated**. Some operating systems translated to `\r\n`. A binary stream leaves it as it is.
2. **Regardless** of how you opened the stream – binary or text:

   a.  When you use the insertion/extraction operator the data is written as **text**. Assuming `0x01` is a one byte integer, ASCII `1` will be written (that is `0x31`).

   b.  If you use the `ostream::write` method, you write the **actual bytes**; no translations happens.  Assuming `0x01` is a one byte integer, `0x01` will be written.
3. If you want to **write the actual bytes**, open the stream in binary mode and use `ostream::write`:

   ```
   ofstream os{ "out.bin", ios::binary };
   if (!os)
     return -1;
   double d = 1.234567;
   os.write((const char*)&d, sizeof d);
   ```
4. If you want to write the **actual bytes as a string**, open the stream in text mode and use the insertion operator:

   ```
   ofstream os{ "out.txt" };
   if (!os)
     return -1;
   double d = 1.234567;
   static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(long long));
   os << hex << *reinterpret_cast<long long*>(&d);
   ```
5. If you want to write a **double as string**, using the **maximum precision** use:

   ```
   os << setprecision(numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10) << d;
   ```
6. Don't use translated & untranslated methods on the same stream.

I do not know if all above examples will work on an Arduino compiler.

Comment: Yes @zdf! This worked for me. The only changes I needed to make were to cast my original tbl1Array[] as a float (single precision) so the AVR could deal with it and to append a "sizeof(float)" to the statement. The line now  reads    fileToOutput.write((const char*)&tbl1Array[i],sizeof(float)); and all is well!! Thanks so much for the help...Mark